# send data from mysql to another mysql server using nodejs

Tags: mysql, data-transfer

how to send data from my SQL to another MySQL server using node JS

i am trying rabbit M Q technique
but not understand the configuration of this technique
please give better solution

Answer (score 0):

MySQL server can interact with another MySQL server directly using [FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html).

Check that it is available and enabled on your servers (or at least on one of them). If so then your node.js program simply creates federated table on one of servers and copies needed data from one server to another one like these tables are posessed on the same server.

For example, if federated table is remote this may look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    {table definition}
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://federated_user@remote_host:9306/federated_db/source_table';

INSERT INTO local_table ( {columns} )
SELECT {columns} FROM federated_table;
```

I.e. your program sends above two queries to one of servers only, and this server accesses another server and retrieves the data itself.

Comment: i want to send live data from one mysql server to another mysql server can i do this using this technique

Comment: @PrakashKumarGupta Of course actual data state is accessed using this method.